# Graphics not appearing when clicking on link. (HTML issue?)

Tags: html, ruby

I have map where a person can click on a marker location to view a building on my University's campus. http://mypower.herokuapp.com/map

Users can then, click on either the picture or title, which both link to the energy usage graph page.

However, when I try to do this from the maps page, the buildings graph page is missing the graph and other graphics elements. In addition, when I click on the tab on the lower left hand corner that says 'graph' of the graph page, it leads me back to the map page, which isn't supposed to happen.

***Now, when I do all of this, but then manually refresh the broken graph page I'm on, the page looks great (the way it should look like).***

Using a combination of html and a little ruby, I create a string of the html for the contents of the popup windows of a map marker.

```
  def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "<center><a href=\"/halls/#{self.id}/\"> #{self.name}</a>
     <br>
     <a href=\"/halls/#{self.id}\"><img src= \"/smallbuildings/#{self.name}.jpg\"></a></center>"
  end
```

Clicking on the link goes to the right page. The graphic elements just aren't rendered for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `target="_parent"` fixed everything.

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "<center><a href=\"/halls/#{self.id}/\" target=\"_parent\"> #{self.name}</a>
     <br>
     <a href=\"/halls/#{self.id}\" target=\"_parent\"><img src= \"/smallbuildings/#{self.name}.jpg\"></a></center>"
  end
```